# Does sweating help to cure the flu

Tags: medical-science, natural-remedies, common-cold, medications, flu

Many people advise you to put some warm clothes on, get under the blankets and sweat a lot to help cure flu/fever.

On one hand there is a lot of opinion on the Internet saying that it does not work, on the other I heard this advice from medical doctors and it seems to work based on my own experience (could be placebo of course). Maybe it is not sweating, but keeping the body warm that helps? That would be ok too, as sweating is just the side effect / indicator that you are really warm and that you drink a lot of liquid as required.

Is there any research / experiment / peer reviewed paper on that?

Comment: Reading this-http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-feed-a-cold/ and this-http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/j7bi9/is_there_any_evidence_that_sweating_out_a/ might help someone to form an answer!

Comment: Is the claim specifically that the sweating **helps cure** the flu? As opposed to more correllational "when your fever breaks, this is frequently accompanied by sweating"

Comment: It's not sweating, it's higher temperature, that help fighting infection (BTW it also destroy some of our cells. That why high and long fever is dangerous).

Comment: No. Sweating from fever is a by product of your body's attempt to increase your internal temperature to, in effect, kill nasty bacteria that may be causing sickness. Sweating is merely the symptom as an outcome of this process. Fully agree with Mike now having read his comments. ..lol

Comment: I wonder what would such a survey be done. "We are looking for flu-positive people. We are going to overheat half of them and measure recovery times. We need at least 100 people. We pay 20EUR/day."