# Does raising your body's temperature help cure flu?

Tags: medical-science, immune-system, flu, virus

I was discussing with a team mate on how to cure the (common) flu *virus*. We had a disagreement about the body temperature effect.

- Con: Some argued that it's better to lower temperature, as it is a practice by nurses.
- Pro: others argued it's better to raise one's temperature due to the effect on the virus.

#### Question

- Does raising temperature –either by covering or metabolizing– help treat influenza?
- What is the mechanism behind it?

#### Related

- [Does sweating help to cure the flu](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/28739/13755)

Comment: I found this article [Do Not Kill a Fever: Fever Kills Viruses](http://www.naturalnews.com/027149_fever_virus_flu.html) that is a pro temperature rising (see _What Fever Is Actually About_ section)

Comment: When a medical intervention is taken to reduce temperature of a fever, it's not to fight a disease but to protect you - high fever can lead to seizures and death.

Comment: Indeed, to my knowledge there's a margin of body temperature where viruses are killed but the body-proteins (say.. brain) is not. Only if the temperature rises to harmful levels will nurses attempt to cool you down.

Comment: Why did you put the word virus back? Usually, one tries to **cure  the flu**, or **kill the flu virus**. If you cure the flu virus, then you're making the flu virus stronger. I don't think this is what most people are going for...

Comment: @James At like 106F or higher. How often does that actually happen? Yet nurses try to lower fevers of only 102F all the time.

Comment: @gebruiker virii are sensible to temperature, bacteries not so much.

Comment: Who said anything about bacteria?